# C++ Infinite Sum Code Hanging? Freezing? I'm not sure

Tags: c++, sum, infinite

Okay, so I'm trying to compute an infinite sum using a for loop instead of a while loop, and the darn code isn't working and I'm not sure why. I get the two "I got here"'s ONCE and then nothing. :\

Does anyone know why my code isn't working and just looks like it freezes or hangs? The loops should end with the way I made them, right? **Here's the current problem code**

```
        check=0;
        cerr << "I got here" << endl;
        for (int m=1;m<m+1;m++)
        {
          cerr << "I got here" << endl;
            for (int n=1;n<n+1;n++)
            {
                if (check==0)
                {
                  anaPhi[i][j][k]=1.0/(m*m*m*n*n*n)
                  *cos(k*deltat*sqrt(5.0)*pi/4.0
                  *sqrt(m*m+4.0*n*n))
                  *sin(m*pi*i*h/4.0)
                  *sin(n*pi*j*h/2.0);
                  check=1;
                }
                else
                {
                  anaPhi[i][j][k]= anaPhi[i][j][k]
                  +1.0/(m*m*m*n*n*n)
                  *cos(k*deltat*sqrt(5.0)*pi/4.0
                  *sqrt(m*m+4.0*n*n))
                  *sin(m*pi*i*h/4.0)
                  *sin(n*pi*j*h/2.0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**I just tested this code and this code also doesn't work!**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int b=0;
    for (int m=1;m<m+1;m=m+2)
    {
        b=cos(b)+sqrt(b);
    }
    cout << b << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple of issues.

1. `if(check=0)` will always set check to 0.
2. Because you use `n= n+2`, it will not ever break. Because at some point you get to n = 0x7FFFFFFE (highest positive even number) and in this case n+1 is > n. It then wraps to 0x80000000 (the most negative signed int, still even) and n+1 will still be > n. If you were able to get n = 0x7FFFFFFF, then n + 1 would actually be less than n due to integer wrap around.
3. There does not seem to be any other way to break out of the for loops than meeting the coditions set.

Comment: But I'm using only odd numbers for my 'm' and 'n' variables.

If it's suppose to be odd numbers that never terminate, is there a way to do odd sums in c++?

Comment: Hmm, that's right, so you should get to 0x7FFFFFFF. It may be that you aren't waiting long enough. Have you tried the loop with a char rather than an int (so it will only go up to 127, and then wrap back around to -128) as a starting point?

Comment: I'll try that now and post back the results.

edit: yeah, the thing just hangs. :\ even on a lousy 127...

I'm going to try and do the even numbers now and see if that changes things.

Comment: Try recompiling with a -O0 flag, the compiler may be optimizing out the condition as being always true.

Comment: I tried both with even and odd integers and then with even and odd chars.
And then I tried incrementing by 1. Still, nothing is working.

Comment: recompile didn't work. I posted the code I recompiled (the for loop part anyway where it gets stuck)

Comment: Okay! So it turns out it might have to do with the cosine, sine, and square root operations. I made a test code that I'll post that also doesn't work, but if I remove the cosine and square root part from it, it will work!

Comment: Just finished compiling for the test code! Turns out it does work it's just SUPER slow.

Comment: No problem (sorry I didn't answer last night, had to get to bed).  Glad it worked out though.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop conditions are wrong. How will `m<m+1` ever be false?

Comment: See the second code I posted. If you compile that. I GUARANTEE it'll end.

There's only so much data that the integer can hold until it can't get any bigger and adding 1 to it just results in the same number back.

Comment: It compiles but it never terminates!

Comment: The second set of code (using m++ as the increment) will terminate when m = 0x7FFFFFFF due to integer wrap around. (0x80000000 is < 0x7FFFFFFF for a signed int).

Answer (score 1):

One more point:

```
 if (check=0)
```

should be

```
 if (check == 0) //^^logical comparison not assignment
```